# Android Runtime error on passing info between activities

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities in my assignment: MainActivity and Country_Activity.

I'm trying to pass 2 inputs the user puts in MainActivity:

```
int counter
String Country
```

But the app always crashes here:  (this is Country_Activity)

```
private void Update(){
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intCounter", 0);
    String country = mIntent.getStringExtra("country");
    counterTextView.setText(intValue);
    countryTextView.setText(country);

    if (country.equals("canada")){
        flagView.setImageResource(R.drawable.canada);
    }
    else if (country.equals("us")){
        flagView.setImageResource(R.drawable.us);
    }
}
```

Specifically on the lines "setText" for each variable.
Everything else works. I can't figure out why they wouldn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the error log ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/luzfv7

Comment: It looks like your `countryTextView` is null at the moment you try to setText. Where do you bind it ? (using findViewById)

Comment: I appreciate your help so very much.   http://prntscr.com/luzhid

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the extras that are passed from one activity to another are read inside on `onCreate()` where all the needed initialization of variables and views is made.  
In your case I see that you get the extras inside another method (maybe it's called inside `onCreate()`?).  
So you forgot to initialize the textviews:

```
TextView counterTextView = findViewById(R.id.countersomething);
TextView countryTextView = findViewById(R.id.countrysomething);
```

also another error that you will encounter later is this:

```
counterTextView.setText(intValue);
```

change it to:

```
counterTextView.setText(String.ValueOf(intValue));
```

Don't pass an integer value inside `setText()` because it will be treated as the id of a resource.